# Google No captcha Recaptcha not working

Tags: php, html, css, captcha, recaptcha

Hope someone could help..i have got the widget to show for the no captcha recaptcha and i have found a code on the internet that i am trying to use because i am not that good with php but it seems to work only partially. everytime that i click the box or that i dont and i try to send an email it says please check the captcha.

this is what i have in my mail confirm.php file which is the server side (i dont think theres a need to post the widget code as it shows and works, which is step 1)

```
$email;$message;$sujet;$header;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email=$_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['message'])){
      $email=$_POST['message'];

}if(isset($_POST['sujet'])){
      $email=$_POST['sujet'];
}if(isset($_POST['header'])){
      $email=$_POST['header'];


    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcIAgETAAAAAEjbARzUsrkgBIHAeE8QmsNE3US-&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==false)
    {
      echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
    }
```

Comment: 1. you're not sanitizing your post's correctly.  This is a serious security flaw.  2. what do you do with the email variable?  If you are trying to make it body, you would use $email += to keep adding to the end of the variable.  3. when you are checking the Boolean type, use === in PHP $response.success === false

Comment: For love of anything use ELSE statements. I don't know where you found this code but it is just horrid...

Comment: im not good with php so if you could suggest a fix for this that would be greatly appreciated:) @phpmeh

Comment: like i said to phpmeh im not too good with php so do you have any suggestions like any lines that i can change or add to better it? @ViruZX

Comment: I'll just pass you one of my integrations... hold on.

Answer (score 2):

Modify this code to your desires.

```
<?
    $APIkey = "API KEY";
    $postresult=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$APIkey&response=$postresult");

    if (strpos($response, 'true')){
        //Captcha is valid, do whatever.
    } else {
        //Captcha is invalid. Tell them to go away.
    }

?>
```

Comment: hi Slava ive tried you code but now it just send an email whether or not i click the captcha :S and the only thing that i did was add my secret key in the "API KEY" section and secret= part

Comment: @Essentialz It shouldn't... try using !strpos($response, 'false') instead. if that doesn't work, review how your form is built.

Comment: hi Slava! i will try that now and i will let you know what happens...thank you for the help so far:)

Comment: yeah im not having any luck Slava, its always give the captcha is invalid message which I made as F**k off spammer and it always says email sent succefully which is another echo in the contact php page and this happens whether I click the captcha or not..i get the same two messages and the email always sends:S

Comment: @Essentialz At this point this is quite strange. Mind pasting the entire code somewhere so I can take look?

Comment: is it ok if i email to you slava?:) spasiba:)

Comment: @Essentialz slava@knyz.org